# Replace or extend UIBarButtonItem selector

Tags: iphone, ios, selector, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm trying to make a custom `UIToolbar` which handles rotation and custom arrangement. When it's in portrait mode some of the barbuttonitems will not be visible, so I add a "more" button from which pops up a little view with these items. My problem is that when my current orientation is portrait and when I select a visible barbuttonitem ( which is not in popup ) I want to close the popup if it's open. I want the smae behavior for the uibarbuttons in the popupview to close the popup after tap.

So I'm trying to replace somehow the UIBarButtonItem's selector with my own, in which I call the already defined actions, like this :

```
-(SEL)extendOriginal:(UIBarButtonItem *) uibb
{
  if (popup) popup.hidden = YES;
  [uibb.target performSelector:uibb.action];
  // return ??  do what ?? 
}
```

But how do I replace the original selector to call this custom method with my custom UIToolbar as its target ? Or how could I "extend" the original selector with this call ? Sorry if question is lame :)

**Edit:** In other words, I want 2 actions with 2 separate targets to be executed when UIBarButtonItem is tapped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to do it, not the prettiest, but it works.

In the custom toolbar class I created in its layout method a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle taps. I've set the `cancelsTouchesInView` to false and in the

```m
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

method I'm returning true only for my toolbar's subviews.

This way the original target and action of each `UIBarButtonItem` remains the same and the supplementary code to handle my popup is the action of the `UIGestureRecognizer`. 
Another problem was to distinguish between the tapped items on the toolbar (the tapped view in `touch.view` is some undocumented view, yay), eventually I did it with some BOOL iVars.

I hope this will help somebody with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This `-(SEL)extendOriginal:(UIBarButtonItem *) uibb` doesn't make any sense.

I assume your are setting the target and the action of the bar button item somewhere. There you can set any method with one argument `id` or `UIBarButtonItem*` as the selector.

Therefore try to change your code to

```
- (void)myMethod:(UIBarButtonItem *) uibb
{
  if (popup) popup.hidden = YES;

  // do cool stuff here
}
```

and set the target as

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Blabla" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: self action: @selector(myMethod:)];
```

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't make sense :) I'm adding the UIBarButtonItems in a viewcontroller which has one of my custom toolbars. My problem is that I want to implement it transparently, so the other viewcontroller where the button actions are defined should have no code for this implementation detail (btw, currently it has, but that's why I wnt a custom toolbar to handle this issue automatically.

Comment: Edited my question, to be more precise.